# How to show current round map in browser?

Tags: battlefield-4

While having 2 monitors it is very cool to see map of the current game in multiplayer. I've found it one time and can't remember where it is.

Comment: I was unaware you could do this and I would be very interested to know as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer - just click `BATTLESCREEN` at blue badge when in-game.